# Camera settings/features are disappeared

Tags: applications, samsung, camera, android-10

There is a Samsung A01 whose default camera settings are like this:

[image: default camera settings]

But for some reason, some camera settings/features located at top bar are disappeared. Does anybody know why? How can I restore it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Approach [suggested here](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Other-Mobile-Devices/Missing-Camera-Features-on-Galaxy-A01/m-p/1320292/highlight/true#M32249) worked:

> The way I got my camera features back is ... by going into the settings going to device care and then click on battery and then changing power mode to optimize which is the first choice.